# How do I redirect through springboot from angular

Tags: java, angular, spring

I have backend springboot that does the redirect

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test/page", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody void getPage(@RequestBody custRequest req, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
   response.sendRedirect("https:www.google.com");
}
```

And the service call like this

```
  getPage(user: User) {
        const bodyString = JSON.stringify(user);
        const header = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/JSON' ,
                                          'Accept' : 'text/html' });
        return this.httpclient.post('/test/page', bodyString, {headers: header, responseType: 'text'} );
  }
```

Button when clicked.

```
  onSubmit(user: User) {
    if (user && user.userID && user.password) {
      this.user.session = this.uuid;
      this.loginService.getLogin(user).subscribe(
        (res) => {
          console.log('post res');
          console.log(res);
        //  window.location.href = data.url; sanitizer
        this.data = this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, res);
        },
        error => {
          console.log('Error', error);
            },
        () => {
          console.log('POST is completed');
        });
```

But in the result page I am not getting a proper landing page. Instead I am staying in the same page and the console would print

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
...

</html>
```

My question is how do I show the actual content?

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, your code fetches the source code of google.com. I'm not sure whether this is the behaviour you want, or you want just a browser redirect. Please explain in more detail what you're trying to achieve. Despite not understanding, I'll do my best to answer.

To do a browser redirect, just do window.location.href = "http://www.w3schools.com";

If you want to fetch a page and show the content of an external page, I think iframe would be the most straight-forward approach.

The one below is NOT RECOMMENDED if the response is a full html page as it's invalid HTML (i.e. can't have html, head, body inside body). It'll also probably download unnecessary files.

Otherwise, create a property in the angular component, let's name it 'myHTML'. Then bind that to the innerHTML property of a html element you create

```
<div [innerHTML]="myHTML"></div>
```

Then once you fetch your URI (I recommend doing it directly -- GET to the final url, the way you did it is odd) just assign the response to the 'myHTML' property

Comment: This is more of a backend side. I am not sending a response back to angular. It will redirect in the springboot server side regardless the request.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can you be more clear?
Do you want to land on the "https://www.google.com" page?

Comment: yes, that's basically what I am trying to do. It would be on more of a springboot side. I am not doing window.location.href since I m not expecting response to get back.